# React is not defined, ReactDOM is not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to run my React code:

src/index.js
Line 1:22:   'React' is not defined     no-undef
Line 11:23:  'React' is not defined     no-undef
Line 42:22:  'React' is not defined     no-undef
Line 60:3:   'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef

I'm a beginner with react, so please be patient and help me find the error. :)

Below let me share my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css';

class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button className="square">
          {/* TODO */}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
      return <Square />;
    }
  
    render() {
      const status = 'Next player: X';
  
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="status">{status}</div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(0)}
            {this.renderSquare(1)}
            {this.renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(3)}
            {this.renderSquare(4)}
            {this.renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(6)}
            {this.renderSquare(7)}
            {this.renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board />
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{/* status */}</div>
            <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  // ========================================
  
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: is `react` is listed as dependency on your `package.json`?

Comment: Sure, http://pastie.org/p/690Ou5tQ8QKnzOx3DmVKgV

Comment: @AlanOmar, yes it is: "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

Comment: I can not figure out what the problem is just by looking at those snippets, can you upload your project to something like codesandbox so i can have a look?